# A question about the natural identification between $Y$ and $Y^{**}$, with $Y$ normed space. Is the following fact obvious?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a reflexive normed space, $Y$ a normed space and $T: X \to Y$ a linear operator.

I consider a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in X and the sequence $\{T(x_n)\}$ in $Y$.

I know that there is a canonical isometry between $Y$ and $Y^{**}$, that I call $ J: Y \to Y^{**} $ such that at each $y \in Y$ associates $\varphi_y$, with $\varphi_y(F)=F(y)$ $ \forall F \in Y^{**} $.

So I can view $ T ( x_{n} ) $ as an element $ \Psi_{n} $ of $ Y^{**} $, using  $ J$.

I would like to know if the following passage is obvious:

\begin{align}
\forall \varphi \in Y^{*}: \quad
   \lim_{n \to \infty} {\Psi_{n}}(\varphi)
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi \left( T \left(  x_{n} \right) \right) 
\end{align}

Does it follow directly from the fact that $J$ is an isometry?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should review the notations in your question and from what I understood I don't think that you even need to use the fact that $J$ is an isometry for that passage as you can see that for any $f \in Y^*$, 
\begin{align*}
\Psi_n(f) &= \varphi_{\Psi_n}(f) & & (\text{ if this is what you meant })\\
& = f(\Psi_n)\\
&= f(T(x_n)).
\end{align*}
So, the two sequences are actually the same (unless you meant something else).